# Android Performance issues in Sencha Touch - Cordova App

Tags: android, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch

I am using Cordova and Sencha Touch 2.3.1 to create both Android and Ios apps. The performance of the IOS app is quite good however the android app performance is very sluggish.

The home page comes is quite good shape but as soon as I open any other page the entire font as well as screen color etc becomes dull and screen response time becomes very high.

Any solutions or pointers will be highly appreciated.

I am using:-
Sencha Touch 2.3.1

Corodva 3.3.1-0.3.1

adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030

Sencha Cmd v4.0.2.67

Comment: You might want to ask this in the Sencha forums. There's going to be way too many things to ask as follow up questions...

Comment: what version of android and which device are you running on?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the issue may be that iOS has a dedicated GPU and compiles mobile Safari with GPU acceleration, whereas most Android devices don't.

There's going to be a lot of potential answers to your question, it's likely that in some or a few ways that your application isn't following best practices which may be causing it to run slowly. The DOM might be too large, you could be instantiating things when you don't need them and forgetting to destroy them and a whole bunch of other stuff. There's a great video about Sencha Touch best practices I wrote a blog post about here: http://www.joshmorony.com/top-10-tips-sencha-touch-best-practices-review/